# More idiomatic way to initialize this kotlin list?

Tags: list, kotlin, immutability, idioms

I want to have an immutable list, since I don't really need the mutability so it likely to just cause bugs. However, the list is a `lateinit var` declared at the class level.

I want to initially populate the list with values from a loop somewhat like this:

```
for (items in someOtherCollection) {
    val itemToAdd = doSomeProcessingOnThisData()
    list.add(itemToAdd)
}
```

However, since the list is immutable, I can't call `add()`. Is there a better way to init a list such as this without simply adding all the values to a second, mutable list and then assigning it to an immutable list?

My current solution is this, but it just seems inefficient:

```
val tmpList = mutableListOf<Data>()
foos.forEach() {
    val itemToAdd = doSomeProcessing()
    foos.add(itemToAdd)
}
this.list = tmpList
```

Comment: FWIW: there's nothing inefficient about your current solution.

Comment: I guess so, since the first list is never actually initialized - it is merely assigned later. It just feels dirty to use two lists, even though I suppose I'm technically not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make a new list processing some data in another collection, try this:

```
this.list = someOtherCollection.map {
    doSomeProcessing()
}
```

Give this a read for a better understanding: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html

Comment: D'oh! I knew that! It's hard to get myself to think functionally.